# Is there an R implementation of the linear ballistic accumulator model or Ratcliff's diffusion model for measuring response time and accuracy?

Tags: experimental-psychology, cognitive-modeling, mathematical-psychology, reaction-time

I am looking for an implementation of the linear ballistic accumulator model or Ratcliff's diffusion model (e.g. in R, MATLAB, or Python).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Here are a few options. I have not tried them yet personally.*

As mentioned below, the [rtdists](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtdists/index.html) package in R is able to fit both LBA and diffusion models.

## Other Options

#### LBA

Scott Brown has a copy of Donkin et al (2009) on his web page with some code in R, Excel, and WinBUGS for fitting the LBA model:

- http://www.newcl.org/publications/DonkinAverellEtAl2009BRM.pdf
- http://www.newcl.org/members/chris/fitLBA.zip

There's also the `glba` package on CRAN by Ingmar Visser.

- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glba/index.html

#### Diffusion model

The Diffussion model is available as a matlab toolbox called ([DMAT](http://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/software/dmat/)).

#### References

- Donkin, C., Averell, L., Brown, S.D., & Heathcote, A. (2009) Getting more from accuracy and response time data: Methods for fitting the Linear Ballistic Accumulator model. Behavior Research Methods, 41, 1095-1110. [PDF](http://www2.psy.unsw.edu.au/Users/CDonkin/publications/brm09b.pdf)
- Vandekerckhove, J., & Tuerlinckx, F. (2008). Diffusion model analysis with MATLAB: A DMAT primer. Behavior Research Methods, 40, 61-72. doi:10.3758/BRM.40.1.61 [PDF](http://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/_pdf/Vandekerckhove2008DMAWM.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

For the diffusion model, there is also Eric-Jan Wagenmakers' "EZ-diffusion model", which you can find [here](http://raoul.socsci.uva.nl/EZ2/).

This paper compares three different pieces of software for estimation of diffusion model parameters:

> von Ravenzwaaij D., & Oberauer, K. (2009). How to use the diffusion
>   model: Parameter recovery of three methods: EZ, fast-dm, and DMAT.
>   Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 53 (6),  463–473.
>   [[PDF]](http://www.donvanravenzwaaij.com/Papers_files/van%20Ravenzwaaij%20%26%20Oberauer,%202009.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The R package diffIRT (http://www.dylanmolenaar.nl/jss1265.pdf) estimates both the Q and the D diffusion models (see his website for the van der Maas et al. paper discussing the differences between these models). R code for the EZ2 approach, which is much faster if that is important for your applications, is http://raoul.socsci.uva.nl/EZ2/.

Answer (score 3):

In the subheading you also mention that you're interested in matlab / python implementations:

I've personally used DMAT in matlab at that's a nice package. However, the python based HDDM package may be one of the best around at the moment (in my opinion) and it has a good user guide.

http://ski.clps.brown.edu/hddm_docs/abstract.html

and the paper associated with the package:

Wieki et al (2013): http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fninf.2013.00014/full

#### References

- Wiecki, T. V., Sofer, I., & Frank, M. J. (2013). HDDM: hierarchical bayesian estimation of the drift-diffusion model in python. Frontiers in neuroinformatics, 7, 14. http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fninf.2013.00014/full

Answer (score 2):

The R package [`rtdists`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtdists/index.html) is another great option:

> Provides response time distributions (density/PDF, distribution function/CDF, quantile function, and random generation): (a) Ratcliff diffusion model based on C code by Andreas and Jochen Voss and (b) linear ballistic accumulator (LBA) with different distributions underlying the drift rate.